# one for the experts: Pluggable gwt module & CompileModule class & XXXX.gwtar file?

Tags: gwt

Question for experts: Pluggable gwt module & CompileModule class & XXXX.gwtar file.

OK this one is for GWT experts!!

I have a GWT app that has widgets. We are shipping 5 widgets out of the box.

The widgets also depend on our API which act as simple DAO pojos

Now when this gets outs to customers. They have a requirement where they want to create their own widgets (as GWT modules) and use them inside our GWT app. Of course, to make things complicated, we cannot give them the source of our app or the API.

Now I know a more prevalent solution here is to have a JSNI API of some sort to have the widget and our app talk to each other, document it and have it rest in peace.

But we are also looking around to see if there are alternatives.

For example, looking at this CompileModule class

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/CompileModule.java?r=10304

Can this be used to "mickey mouse" our sources.

It looks like this compiler will / could compile a module into a XXXX.gwtar file and in theory that might all customers would need to compile there custom module.

Any thoughts? Are we on to something here or is it dead end.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like GWTAR  is dead end for you. From the looks of it gwtar file is not enough to start the compilation, you will need to provide sources as well. Its sole purpose is to speed up compilation of really big applications, it will not be very helpful for your case.